# Conditional search in vba

Tags: vba, search, conditional-statements, highlight

This is to find and highlight the instances of certain words in a Word document.
In the TargetList in the following code, how do I insert these words:
1. "^$ however"
2. "^# however" 
3. "^$ respectively"

(I mean, a conditional search; searching for the instance of "any letter" "space" "however" combination, for example.)
Thanks in advance.

```
Sub HighlightTargets2()

Dim range As range
Dim i As Long
Dim TargetList

TargetList = Array("asset and liability method", "auditor's", "Black Scholes", "comprised of", "comprised primarily of", "primarily comprised of", "defined benefit", "defined contribution", "effected", "effecting", "effective interest method", "effective interest rate method", "footnote", "high quality", "however ", "in the U.S.", "in the us", "kmpg", "kpgm", "kgpm", "lump sum", "manger", "more likely than not recognition", "more likely than not threshold", "multi-", "non-", "option-pricing", "payer", "percentage of completion method", "percentage of completion accounting", "polices", "post-", "pro-", "proforma", "re-", "related party transaction", "respectively ", "^# respectively", "respectfully", "revenues", "see note", "see footnote", "self insurance", "Self insured", "stop loss", "straight line basis", "straight line method", "the this", "the a", "third party transaction", "website", "-wide", " wide", "year end")

For i = 0 To UBound(TargetList)

Set range = ActiveDocument.range

With range.Find
.Text = TargetList(i)
.Format = False
.MatchCase = False
.MatchWholeWord = False
.MatchWildcards = False
.MatchSoundsLike = False
.MatchAllWordForms = False

Do While .Execute(Forward:=True) = True
range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow

Loop

End With
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you are missing some nugget of info like this is for a Word doc or something.  Also, that is not Vb.NET code, *maybe* vba, but again there is no context.

Comment: You are correct; thank you, Plutonix, for notifying me of these important things. I have edited my question accordingly.